# CUPS does not recognize bluetooth receipt printer

Tags: printing, cups, bluetooth, printer

I've been given for testing purpose a mobile receipt printer and I am trying to set it up in cups. I've successfuly connected to it via `lubuntu blueman-manager` and printed test page via `cat testfile.txt > /dev/rfcomm0` and for the sake of some java application that will use it I need to set it up in cups. I get into cups web admin page, click `add printer` but the printer neither port are not found. Why? I've changed permissions under `/usr/lib/cups/backend/` and now I have situation from screenshot[image: ![None printers available]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKRiP.png)Now what?!

Comment: I believe there's an add-on package for bluetooth with CUPS, `bluez-cups`.  Do you have that installed?

Comment: I did not have installed this package, I've installed it, restarted comp and same result, printer is not detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does CUPS not have an option for "generic serial printer"?

Then point it to /dev/rfcomm0

Have you checked the rights on:
/usr/lib/cups/backend/serial
and /dev/rfcomm0

May only root accessible?

Found this on Arch Linux Forum:
 [(Solved) Generic Serial Printer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88250)

Comment: I've changed permissions on `/usr/lib/cups/backend/` via `sudo chmod -R 777 *` and this was bad idea, since if I try to add printer under cups admin page, now I cannot add any printer since the list is empty! I've added screenshot under original question!

Comment: yes, that was bad. chmod go+rx serial would have been better.

Comment: how do I revert this stupid mistake?

Comment: Reinstall CUPS with 'apt-get install --reinstall cups' perhaps?. Or copy the rights for the 10 files in that folder from a different Installation. 'chmod go-w /usr/lib/cups/backend/*' and then go from there.

Comment: I have lubuntu will now reinstall whole cups!

Comment: I've reinstalled cups with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cups` and now I see in admin webpage under Netword printers options `LPD/LPR Host or Printer` and `AppSocket/HP JetDirect`. Still not ok!

Comment: have you tried applying go+rx to serial now?

Comment: @Ales Strgies yes I have, same result!